# Neyman-Pearson hypothesis testing and composite alternative hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

I am in love with the idea of setting up a statistical test à la Neyman-Pearson when possible, because it is just so intuitive. Most of times, $H_0$ is some kind of point hypothesis, but $H_1$ is actually a composite one, and I cannot formulate the likelihood ratio consistently.

What is the most consistent way to proceed in your experience?

Comment: Are you sure you have asked the question as intended? Except in toy examples, $H_1$ (the alternate hypothesis) is *always* composite.  What, then, do you mean by "formulate the likelihood ratio consistently"?

Comment: I may have badly formulated the question, as I am still a novice in this field. What I mean is that on textbooks $H_1$ is presented in different ways, depending on the exercise, but usually the only framework presented with some rigour is the Neyman-Pearson test, where $H_1$ *must* be simple, in order to compute a rejection region based on a likelihood ratio. Researching afterwards, I just stumbled upon the Wald test, that formulates the rejection region as a function of the log-likelihood function rather than the ratio, so I may have found an answer. Is it?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59489; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365033; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440277; [etc](https://www.google.com/search?q=neyman-pearson+composite+test+site%3Astats.stackexchange.com)